# How to get the Mat object from the Byte[] in openCV android?

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, bitmap

I am working with OpenCV library in Android.  I have a class which implements `PictureCallBack`.

The override method `onPictureTaken()` is as given below,

```
     @Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Saving a bitmap to file");
    // The camera preview was automatically stopped. Start it again.
    mCamera.startPreview();
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);

    // Write the image in a file (in jpeg format)
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mPictureFileName);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();

    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
    }
}
```

As I want image data to be used further in image processing in stead of saving and reloading the image.

What is the most efficient way for getting the Mat object from the Byte array?
I have already tried these approaches:

1. Don't know what happened to the image.

   `Mat m=new Mat(); 
      m.put(0,0,data);`
2. Converting to Bitmap then use `bitmapToMat()` 
   In this case , red color becomes blue .

I also don't have any problem in saving the image for future use,but this leads me an exception because the file not have been generated yet, when I am using the previously stored image.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to specify width and height of the image/Mat and channels depth.

```
Mat mat = new Mat(width, height, CvType.CV_8UC3);
mat.put(0, 0, data);
```

Make sure you are using correct type of Mat. Maybe your data is not in 3 bytes RGB format and you should use another type e.g. `CvType.CV_8UC1`.
Good luck!

Comment: can you please define data?? what it is?

Comment: `data` is `byte[]` array which contains series of pixels in proper format. It could be obtain from eg. `BufferedImage` - `byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();`

Comment: height and width params are wrong I guess. Mat mat = new Mat(height, width CvType.CV_8UC3);

Answer (score 14):

The best and easiest way is like this:

```
byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("aaa.jpg"));
Mat mat = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(bytes), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

Comment: I see this pasted on a lot of similar questions, but it results in a crash related to memory. It seems like this may not be a viable solution when you have an image that is larger than the intended Mat output.

Answer (score 1):

opencv has a neat way to writing Mats to files - it can generate different formats based on the file extension provided. Here is a minimal example:

```
    public void writeImageToFile(Mat image, String filename) {

    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(root, filename);

    Highgui.imwrite(file.getAbsolutePath(), image);

    if (DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG,
                "writing: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " (" + image.width()
                        + ", " + image.height() + ")");
}
```

if red and blue is swapped then it sounds like your byte data from onPictureTaken() is in BGRA format. You can swap it to RGBA using:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(bgrImg, rgbImg, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);
```

the format is actually device specific - on one device I had it comes through as YUV.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the next works fine for me:

**Java side**:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = mTextureView.getBitmap(mWidth, mHeight);
    int[] argb = new int[mWidth * mHeight];
    // get ARGB pixels and then proccess it with 8UC4 OpenCV convertion
    bitmap.getPixels(argb, 0, mWidth, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
    // native method (NDK or CMake)
    processFrame8UC4(argb, mWidth, mHeight);
```

**OpenCV side (NDK)**:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL com_native_detector_Utils_processFrame8UC4
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jint width, jint height, jintArray frame) {

    jint *pFrameData = env->GetIntArrayElements(frame, 0);
    // it is the line:
    Mat mFrame = Mat(height,width,CV_8UC4,pFrameData).clone();
    // your code..
    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(frame, pFrameData, 0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the imdecode method which comes as part of opencv (this is for emgucv but it should have a similar operation on other versions of opencv, syntax might just be different)

Example:

```
byte [] imageArray
Mat dest

CvInvoke.Imdecode(imageArray, ImreadModes.Unchanged, dest)
```