# Android convert byte array from Camera API to color Mat object openCV

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I'm trying to take data captured off the camera API and do color postprocessing.  My issue is that while I can convert a byte[] object to a Mat object, I cannot get the color channels without receiving an error.  I started with the following post: [How to get the Mat object from the Byte[] in openCV android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113190/how-to-get-the-mat-object-from-the-byte-in-opencv-android) but that implementation does not work.

Here is the relevant code:

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // The camera preview was automatically stopped. Start it again.
    mCamera.startPreview();
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);

    // Write the image in a file (in jpeg format)
    File pictureFile_interp = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    try {

        //Now try to convert and save.
        Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        Size sz = params.getPictureSize();

        //ERROR IN THE LINE BELOW!!!!
        Mat raw = new Mat(sz.height,sz.width,CvType.CV_8UC4);
        raw.put(0, 0, data);
        Mat targ = Highgui.imdecode(raw, 0);

        orig = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(targ, orig, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
        //Imgproc.cvtColor(targ, fixed, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);

        //now we have the target we want...let's interpolate.
        interp = interpExperiment(orig,interpBy);
        Highgui.imwrite(pictureFile_interp.toString(), interp);

    } finally{

    }

}
```

When I try that code, I get an exception:

```
Provided data element number should be multiple of the Mat channels count (3)
```

Instead I replace the problematic line with

```
Mat raw = new Mat(sz.height,sz.width,CvType.CV_8U);
raw.put(0, 0, data);
Mat targ = Highgui.imdecode(raw, 0);
```

I can get a grayscale image.  What am I doing wrong with

```
Mat raw = new Mat(sz.height,sz.width,CvType.CV_8UC3);
```

?  I've looked at quite a few stackoverflow posts addressing this and none work for the color matrix.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The exception happens at the

    raw.put(0,0,data); line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround to this: using Bitmapfactory, you can convert the byte[] array to a bitmap, which you can in turn correctly convert into a Mat.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data.length);
Mat orig = new Mat(bmp.getHeight(),bmp.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC3);
Bitmap myBitmap32 = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmap32, orig);

Imgproc.cvtColor(orig, orig, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB,4);
```

Seems there should be a better way but this works.

Comment: Have you found a more direct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

```
public Mat Byte_to_Mat(byte[] data) {

    Mat jpegData = new Mat(1, data.length, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    jpegData.put(0, 0, data);


    Mat bgrMat = new Mat();
    bgrMat = Highgui.imdecode(jpegData, Highgui.IMREAD_COLOR);
```

Comment: This code is work. i didn't know how to use `Highgui.imdecode`
But now I am know :)
Thanks @Idol

Comment: I don't know how this isn't getting more votes. This worked for me, although sadly it was slower than decoding to a bitmap :(

Answer (score 1):

When you use:

```
raw.put(0, 0, data);
```

you would normally be setting all the channel values for pixel at point (0,0); so if you have a 3 channel image, then you would provide a byte array of three values like:

```
byte data[] = {1,2,3}
```

You are allowed to set more than one pixel at a time but the key point is that your data array needs to be multiple of the channels as otherwise opencv won't know what to see all the pixel values to. So, for example, again for a 3 channel Mat, you are allowed:

```
byte data[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

this will set pixel value (0,0) to (1,2,3) and (0,1) to (4,5,6)

but not:

```
byte data[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
```

as this as 7 elements,which is not a multiple of 3.

You get the error you are seeing as your data array length is not a multiple of the number of channels.

You should check what format your data array is actually in. From my experience on my devices it tends to be YUV which has different dimensions to RGB so there will be some conversion required.

Comment: Ahh, this makes sense - I just wasn't sure what the proper Mat construction was.  It would make sens for the data format to be YUV though.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the data you will be getting would be in `YUV` format. It is generally 1 channel matrix with height as 1.5 times the height of the image if it were RGB or grayscale and same width.

```
Mat raw = new Mat(sz.height*1.5,sz.width,CvType.CV_8UC1); // YUV data
raw.put(0, 0, data);
orig = new Mat(sz.height, sz.height, CvType.CV_8UC4); // RGBA image
Imgproc.cvtColor(raw, orig, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21); // This might vary depending on the camera image type
```

Comment: Thanks!  The Mat class doesn't appear to have a constructor that takes (double,int,int), so I converted the 1.5*sz.height to integer and tried.  The result was a completely green image.

Comment: After converting to RGBA? Or you saved raw Mat?

Comment: I tried the exact code posted, resulted in the green images.  I think something got messed up in the type conversion (i.e. the 4th line you posted).  

I am using a Nexus 5.  I thought I saw somewhere that this phone saved as YUV...

I converted to a bitmap and it worked well as per my most recent post.

Answer (score 0):

The changes made by @user3502402 are absolutely correct. You just needed to change the flag to 1 from 0 in `Highgui.imdecode(raw, 1)` and the code gives perfect coloured photographs

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is ===>

int width = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width; // get width of camera preview size

int height = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height; // get height of camera preview size

Mat mat = new Mat(height + height/2,width, CvType.CV_8UC1); //Create mat object for NV21 byte[]

mat.put(0, 0, bytes); //Put byte[] into mat to generate raw mat

Mat mRgba = new Mat(); //Create new mat object to convert NV21 mat to RGBA

Imgproc.cvtColor( mat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV21,4); //Convert mat ot new rgba mat

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); //Create same bitmap which camera preview size has. o.w. it will throw error.

Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba,bitmap); // Finally convert mat object to bitmap.

Holaaaaa....

Tested on personal project and it is working 100%

Comment: Let me know what issue you are facing with above code. And then vote ;)