# Converting inputFrame from Camera to HSI using OpenCV in Android

Tags: android, opencv

I want to convert an image from Android camera to HSI format using OpenCV.
The problem is when I use the following method

```
private Mat rgb2hsi(Mat rgbFrame) {
    Mat hsiFrame = rgbFrame.clone();

    for( int i = 0; i < rgbFrame.rows(); ++i ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < rgbFrame.cols(); ++j ) {
            double[] rgb = rgbFrame.get(i, j);
            Log.d(MAINTAG, "rgbFrame.get(i, j) array size = " + rgb.length);
            double colorR = rgb[0];
            double colorG = rgb[1];
            double colorB = rgb[2];

            double minRGB = min(colorR, colorG, colorB);
            double colorI = (colorR + colorG + colorB) / 3;
            double colorS = 0.0;

            if(colorI > 0) colorS = 1.0 - (minRGB / colorI);

            double colorH;
            double const1 = colorR - (colorG / 2) - (colorB / 2);
            double const2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(colorR, 2) + Math.pow(colorG, 2) + Math.pow(colorR, 2)
                            - (colorR * colorG) - (colorR * colorB) - (colorG * colorB));

            colorH = Math.acos(const1 / const2);
            if(colorB > colorG) colorH = 360 - colorH;

            double[] hsi = {colorH, colorS, colorI};
            hsiFrame.put(i, j, hsi);
        }
    }


    return hsiFrame;
}
```

It shows an error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Provided data element number (3) should be multiple of the Mat channels count (4)
```

I search for a while to figure out the cause of this error.
I found that I put an array of size 3 instead of 4.
[Android convert byte array from Camera API to color Mat object openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202130/android-convert-byte-array-from-camera-api-to-color-mat-object-opencv/)
I wonder what Type of image receive from Android Camera.
Why when I get an array of size 4?
How to convert an image received from Android camera to HSI and preview on the screen?

The following is the overrided method *onCameraFrame*

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat outputFrame = inputFrame.rgba();

    /* Get RGB color from the pixel at [index_row, index_column] */
    int index_row = 0;
    int index_column = 0;
    final double[] mRgb_pixel = outputFrame.get(index_row, index_column);

    /* Show the result */
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int r = (int) mRgb_pixel[0];
            int g = (int) mRgb_pixel[1];
            int b = (int) mRgb_pixel[2];
        /* Set RGB color */
            mRred_textview.setText("Red\n" + Double.toString(mRgb_pixel[0]));
            mGreen_textview.setText("Green\n" + Double.toString(mRgb_pixel[1]));
            mBlue_textview.setText("Blue\n" + Double.toString(mRgb_pixel[2]));
            mColor_textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
        }
    });

    if(mPreviewType == PreviewType.GB) {
        outputFrame.convertTo(outputFrame, CvType.CV_64FC3);
        return getGBColor(rgb2hsi(outputFrame));
    } else if (mPreviewType == PreviewType.HSI) {
        outputFrame.convertTo(outputFrame, CvType.CV_64FC3);
        return rgb2hsi(outputFrame);
    } else {
        return outputFrame;
    }
}
```

My MainActivity implements *CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2*

[Edit]
I think that the reason why it return an array of size 4 is because the frame is in RGBA format, not RGB format.
Therefore, how to convert RGBA to HSI and preview the frame on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your hsiFrame is a 4 channel image and your hsi array has only 3 values. You need to add one term corresponding to alpha channel to your hsi array. Making **either** of the following changes should work for you:

```
1. double[] hsi = {colorH, colorS, colorI, rgb[3]};
2. Mat hsiFrame = new Mat(rgbFrame.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
```

Hope this helps.