# Preparing bitmap byte[] data to pass to jni

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, bitmap

I would like to pass a bitmap from my android class to my native c++ class through the jni, and then perform opencv processing the other side.

I don't understand how to prepare the data to go into a byte[] array, using something like getPixels. Do I need to consider RGB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert `Bitmap` to `Mat`. `org.opencv.android.Utils` class having the utility conversion method . It takes `Bitmap` as parameter of type `ARGB_8888` or `RGB_565`.

```
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
private void convertToMat(Bitmap bitmap){
    Mat mat = new Mat();
    Bitmap bmp32 = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp32, mat);
}
```

This is just one way . Have a look into [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113190/how-to-get-the-mat-object-from-the-byte-in-opencv-android) for more. Thx